# Php with html on local file

Tags: php

Is it possible to use Php on file:///? I want to test it in a local computer.
Please include it in a html file.

Comment: *"Is it possible to use Php on file:///?"* - No.

Comment: *"Also..."* - That makes your question too broad now.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use Php on file:///?

You can run PHP from a command line, but it sounds like you want to trigger it from a web browser, in which case the answer is: No.

> I want to test it in a local computer.

Install an HTTP server with support for PHP on that computer then.

Comment: @Bytemain — A server is essential. PHP's built-in server is a server. It is an acceptable choice in many circumstances (personally I would avoid it for all but the most trivial test cases in favour of more similar to the production environment). It is still a server.

Comment: @Bytemain — Why not? Do you think I should recommend a specific HTTP server? I was deliberately trying not to do that.

Answer (score -2):

PHP is a server side programming langauage so you need to install a local server in order to run it on your computer. If you are using windows Apperv (https://www.appserv.org/en/) could do it. It has mysql support as well.

Comment: Sure, but what they're asking is a multi-part question.

Comment: No need for a server, PHP has its own buit-in web server. Run `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000` to start it at 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: You are right, that is the easiest way. The local server could be useful in case of longer development maybe.

Comment: PHP has a built in server?! Thanks for that information! +1